# Python selection on Django queryset Result

Tags: python, django

I have the need to sort my django queryset result (top five large values)

i am sorting this by selection sort

```
def sortTopFive(allPois):                   # selection sort
    res=[]
    for i in range(0,4):
            large =allPois[i]
            for ele in range(i, len(allPois)):
                    if allPois[ele]['count']>=large['count']:
                            ele, large = large , ele
                    else :
                            continue
            res[i]=large
    return res
```

all[i]['count'] is the an integer

the error that i get is

```
'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

this Question might be too dumb, i am new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many, many things wrong with this code. Some of the obvious:

- Swapping `ele` and `large` doesn't actually do anything to the list, it just rebinds the name `ele` to what was previously `large` but that name is then immediately rebound to the next element in the list anyway;
- `res[i]` will give you an IndexError because the list is empty; you probably want to do `res.append(i)`.

However, unless you're doing this as an algorithm learning exercise, I have no idea why you want to do it at all. Python has a perfectly good built-in `sort()` function, which is many times more efficient than your code - and on top of that, Django's querysets themselves support sorting directly in the database, which is even better.

Comment: i am doing order by on 2 items, per date (ASC) and count(DESC) and now i need count(DESC) for overall highest counts

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do that in the query itself

## Example

```
This will get them ordered by price for example desc
Module.objects.all().order_by("-price")
```

OR

```
#If you want to remove duplicates just do this
Module.objects.all().order_by("-price").distinct('price')
#or limit results to 5
Module.objects.all().order_by("-price").distinct('price')[:5]
```

Comment: i am doing order by on 2 items, per date (ASC) and count(DESC)
now i need count(DESC)